# check for dates in couple of columns and create a new column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, feature-engineering

I am new to Python. In a Data frame, there are two columns, DOB (Date of Birth) and DOD (Date of Death). I want to create a new categorical column in the dataframe with name "IS_ALIVE". The condition for this new field, IS_ALIVE should be "1" when DOB is populated and DOD is null; IS_ALIVE should be "0" when DOB and DOD both are not null, meaning, some date is populated the DOD.
[image: Data I am looking at]

I searched and tried multiple ways, no luck. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create boolean mask with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isna.html) and [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notna.html) chained by `&` (bitwise AND) and convert to integers for `True/False` to `1/0`:

```
df['IS_ALIVE'] = (df.DOB.notna() & df.DOD.isna()).astype(int)
#for old versions of pandas
#df['IS_ALIVE'] = (df.DOB.notnull() & df.DOD.isnull()).astype(int)
```